# create Carousel in React Native like example image

Tags: javascript, react-native, carousel

I want to create slider in carousel in react native like the example image below, Is there any library out there or some tutorial to make like the example image ?
Or can someone write a part of code to help me write such a slider?
can i write this carousel with FlatList?

[image: slider_carousel]

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own slider with ScrollView or FastList.

Check this tutorial to understand the basics of creating a carousel with ScrollView https://blog.logicwind.com/carousel-using-react-native-scrollview/

Also, you could use [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel) library which offers many features and customizations.